# a thread doesn't work when I use ToListAsync method

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, ef-core-3.1

I have an *EF Core* program.

**Code**

```cs
class EagerLoading
{
    public async void load()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a");
        var teams = await loadTeamsAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("c");
    }
    public async Task<List<Team>> loadTeamsAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("b");
        using (var context = new SchoolContext())
        {
            return await context.teams.
                ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
//Entry method
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new EagerLoading().load();
}
```

**Output**

```
a
b
```

**Expected**

```
a
b
c
```

## Question

where am I wrong? why the `Console.WriteLine("c");` doesn't execute?

Comment: If you put a `Console.WriteLine` after the `context.teams.ToListAsync()` call does it get called? From what I can tell, you're request still hasn't been returned

Comment: `load` is an async void method. async void methods are not recommended exactly due to your example. You have a sync main method, you are calling a async void method, but behind the scenes there is an async action that finishes after the main method is done.

Comment: your code need ReadKey() in Main method

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to put a `ReadKey` or similar in the `Main` method to stop the application from *exiting*.

`Load` is an `async void` (which should be ringing alarm bells) and runs *unobserved*, in-turn there is a high probability of the application *exiting* before it finishes in the way you expect (or in this case writing to the *console*).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new EagerLoading().load();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

<sub>***Note*** : You should only ever be using on async voids on event handlers (or constructs that logically represent event handlers), it's more-or-less the primary reason they exist.</sub>

Comment: I want to emphasize that this is just a bandaid. A correct solution would be make the `load` method return a Task, make the Main method also return async Task and await the load method, and finally remove the then unnecessary ReadKey.